# If a broad long-term investment in the stock market is such a good deal, why don't banks do the "obvious" things?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets, risk, risk-management

There is a fundamental discrepancy or paradox that has been keeping me, and many others, away from the stock market. Before I explain it, let me mention some selected popular questions on this site in which the consensus is that in the long term a broad investment in the stock market will yield a substantially positive average annual return rate:

[Why should we expect stocks to go up in the long term?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/81126/why-should-we-expect-stocks-to-go-up-in-the-long-term)

[Why do people claim that Stock Markets are broadly exponential in the long term?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/118002/why-do-people-claim-that-stock-markets-are-broadly-exponential-in-the-long-term)

[Why isn't everybody rich?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/94671/why-isnt-everybody-rich?newreg=10e564a2336747209c86109aa8cc7672)

[Stock market long term risks](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/94619/stock-market-long-term-risks)

[Is it a lie that you can easily make money passively in the stock market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/94501/is-it-a-lie-that-you-can-easily-make-money-passively-in-the-stock-market)

[Are Index Funds really as good as “experts” claim?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/85597/are-index-funds-really-as-good-as-experts-claim)

In view of all this consensus, we can almost say that it has become "common knowledge" that investing in the broad stock market (sufficient diversification) from a long-term perspective (several decades) is a very good investment strategy. More precisely, the consensus seems to be that there is some average annual return rate, say 3% (replace this number by something higher/lower if you prefer), such that if your investment is diversified enough and your timespan is long enough, the risk that your actual average annual return rate drops below that rate tends towards zero.

**Now comes the first question:** *Why doesn't any (serious) bank offer a savings account with a fixed 2% interest rate for an unlimited amount of time?*

After all, a large bank has the optimal prerequisites for diversification and holding stocks for many decades, and if the above is true, then they would still earn at least 1% of their customer's account values each year by essentially doing not very much except buying and selling some index funds according to what customers want to withdraw or pay in.

My own first objection to the question would be the following: *If there is a market crash and at the same time a lot of customers want to withdraw money from their accounts, the bank might be in big trouble because the total value of the stocks owned by the bank could be less than what the customers want to withdraw.*

However, I feel that this is not *really* an objection because even without the above "obvious product" banks will *always* be in trouble if their customers want to withdraw too much money at once.

What's bothering me, even more, is the

**Second question:** *Why don't all banks borrow a huge amount of money from the central bank and invest it in the stock market on a broad, long-term basis?*

As far as I know, banks can borrow money from the central bank at quite low-interest rates (much less than the expected long-term average annual return rate of the broad stock market), in Europe that interest rate is currently even *negative*. So why don't all banks just buy index funds using this free money and just hold them forever, watching them grow in value?

---

Edit: After the first few answers (and some downvotes) I immediately realized that it was a big mistake to specialize the question in the sense that I only asked why *banks* don't do the "obvious" things, rather than having simply asked why *no-one* or  *no specialized company* does the "obvious" things. I am very glad that in the further course of events my question was received in a slightly more abstract way. Thank you all for your answers and upvotes, earning me a gold badge with my very first question on this site! If one could only trade in those badges for their real-world counterparts... ;-)

Comment: Banks have found another way to profit from the stock market that has even more leverage and zero risk to them --- advisory and management fees.

Comment: "Why don't all banks borrow a huge amount of money from the central bank and invest it in the stock market on a broad, long-term basis?" This has been asked [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/103626) and [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/105437).

Comment: *Why don't all banks borrow a huge amount of money from the central bank and invest it in the stock market on a broad, long-term basis?* Banking regulations limit how much banks can invest, the amount of risk they can take  as well as how much cash they must maintain for daily operations

Comment: I saw this question had a downvote. I've upvoted this question and I would encourage others to do the same, even though the premise it's being asked from is really flawed - I do think there's value in the resulting discussion.

Comment: @dwizum - I agree and this also pertains to the closing of questions.  If someone makes a good faith attempt in seeking information about or clarification of a financial problem, it shouldn't matter if the premise is flawed.

Comment: its my understanding that in the uk, banks were forced through regulation to keep their retail banking and investment banking arms separate after the financial crisis in 2008 because of the economic problems it caused at the time. It was also my understanding that banks can only borrow from the bank of england for the purpose of lending to other businesses. No idea if there were similar measures in other countries

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_investment_and_retail_banking

Comment: "Why doesn't any (serious) bank offer a savings account with a fixed 2% interest rate for an unlimited amount of time?" - they do! See https://www.absa.co.za/personal/save-invest/products/depositor-plus/ (above the minimum interest bearing balance of ZAR15,000, the interest is 4.95% pa, and it goes up from there.)

Comment: PS. I joined this Stack Exchange Account just to say that :)

Comment: When I wrote that 'Why isn't everybody Rich' question, I didn't expect it to be so popular. Glad to see others thinking the same way as me and asking the same questions!

Comment: It's because of your first objection. Because of your objection to your first objection, the government guarantees bank deposits, but also because the government is guaranteeing the deposits, they only let the bank invest in things with a low risk of going down too much.

Comment: In Canada, wealthsimple has recently introduced pretty much exactly this: an account with 2.4% interest, no fees, backed by CIPF, and even with plans to make it usable as a chequing account with a debit card some time this year. They're an investment company however, not a bank, so they're cutting into banks' business rather than vice versa

Comment: 2% seems pretty low - I have heard a typical market return of 6-8% per year, after adjusting for inflation.  Banks can *already* "earn" the 1% (or whatever) spread by simply lending money at a higher interest rate than they pay in savings, but this rate is typically *less* than the expected return on market investments (otherwise why would businesses pay that interest rate to fund their businesses?)

Comment: You are wrong, there is perpetual bonds which offer 1-2% annually. Those are not protected from inflation, mostly. Well, but they give you what you want. Also some financial professionals did calculate long-term real rate of bonds including all risks, and it ended somewhere around 1-2%.

Comment: Because they run a much easier and higher roi business. See here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/116967/why-do-banks-loan-at-apr-%e2%89%a4-3-rather-than-investing-that-principal-in-etfs/117000#117000

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Fundamentally, I think there's a high level (and perhaps unsatisfying) answer to this. It's because that's not "banking" as a business, and a bank is established to do banking, not to get into the stock market. In other words, this question strikes me about the same as asking,

> *why don't ice cream shops stop selling ice cream, and instead get in the business of selling pancakes? After all, you can make a lot of money selling pancakes.*

Well yes, you can get rich selling pancakes, but not every business is a pancake shop. Certainly, some businesses get rich selling pancakes, but other businesses with different motivations and risk tolerances decide to sell ice cream instead.

To make this clear in your banking context: such a business would essentially be called a hedge fund or investment management company, not a bank. It's fine if a company wants to be a hedge fund, but a company that is calling itself a bank can't secretly switch over to being a hedge fund, and still call itself a bank while supporting "banking" activities for normal consumers.

From a more practical perspective, most jurisdictions have carefully developed regulations that would essentially prohibit a business calling itself a bank from doing what you're discussing. Essentially, these regulations exist because of my first point - the business model you're describing isn't "banking." And, regulations are designed around that, in the sense that regulations keep banks acting like banks and stop them from trying to act like something that isn't a bank.

I'm editing to clarify a portion of your question, as an example of this disconnect. You said,

> As far as I know, banks can borrow money from the central bank at quite low-interest rates

That's not really the whole story. Think of it this way. Imagine if you were to walk into a retail bank right now, and ask for a loan for a million dollars. The bank would certainly ask you some questions, including asking what you intended to do with that money and how you could show proof that you are able to pay it back. If you were able to prove that you have a large and stable income and that you were planning on using the million dollars to purchase a home that's actually worth a million dollars, you might get approved. But what if you told the bank, *"I'm actually empty-handed, but I'm going to go invest this in the stock market, I think I have a proven way to make a positive return"* - they might deny you on the spot, or at least they might have a lot more questions for you!

The relationship between central banks and retail banks is fundamentally similar. A retail bank can't just call up the central bank and say, *"please wire me a billion dollars"* and instantly, the money shows up. Retail banks essentially have to go through a process of validating their operational intentions, showing proof that they can pay the loan back, and perhaps even putting up collateral before the money changes hands. And, a retail bank with no collateral who indicated that they wanted to play the stock market would almost certainly get turned down by the central bank.

I'm making another edit to address another core flaw in your assumptions. You said,

> we can almost say that it has become "common knowledge" that investing in the broad stock market (sufficient diversification) from a long-term perspective (several decades) is a very good investment strategy

While that may be a sound *theory* it's not a practical method for a bank to keep or invest assets, because of liquidity and predictability. It may be accurate to say that "in the long term" a diversified stock portfolio can be bulletproof. But banks can't issue cash to deposit customers based on long-term theories. They have to be able to predict the availability of funds very well - the stability of their outcomes, not just the expected result. In other words, if a bank has $10 billion in assets, they need to know *precisely* how much of that will be available to them tomorrow, or next Tuesday, or in six months. Your stock market theory may have the right expected outcome (positive growth), but it's got far too much potential variance on any particular day. Yes, "in the long run" you may make money, but can you tell me exactly how much cash you'll have next Tuesday? No, you can't. You might have an acceptable expected outcome *on Average* for all "next Tuesdays" - but what if coronavirus takes off in the US this weekend? Or something else happens? Banks aren't just concerned about the expected outcome, they're also concerned about variability in the range of expected outcomes. People do "banking activities" like deposit their paycheck into a deposit account, or take out a credit card loan, with the expectation of stability and availability of funds. Those "features" which are essentially the definition of retail banking come as a trade-off in terms of a slightly lower return (compared to your stock market portfolio).

Comment: *the business model you're describing isn't "banking."* Exactly. 
 General Motors has a net worth of $46 billion, and only gets a 4.75% Return on Investment.  Why don't they sell all their assets, pay off all debts and invest the $46B in the stock market???  Because then they wouldn't be a car company. Taking this to it's logical conclusion... why doesn't **every** company sell all their assets, pay their debts and invest the money in the stock market?

Comment: I would add that there are companies whose business model is essentially what OP describes, namely hedge funds and investment management companies.

Comment: Counterexample: [Iced tea company pivots to blockchain.](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/12/21/long-island-iced-tea-micro-cap-adds-blockchain-to-name-and-stock-soars.html)

Comment: @quarague I've edited in your comment.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins That company have since tanked and is being investigated by... I think SEC? Something real shady happened and I don't recommend people doing it.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I'm not sure if that was meant to be a serious counter example or a joke, but have you seen [what's happened to them since 2017?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Blockchain_Corp)

Comment: @RonJohn The simple answer is there will no longer BE a market to buy stocks in. The entire economy will completely collapse if companies stop doing what they're doing and "invest in stocks".

Comment: @Nelson that's my point... :)

Comment: Isn't another point that companies could get a better return by investing money in their own company rather than the stock market? Most (successful) companies have a better margin than 3%, don't they? It's not like their money is just sitting around doing nothing if they don't invest it in the stock market.

Comment: @Kat *Most (successful) companies have a better margin than 3%, don't they?* I don't know of a reliable way to answer that holistically, but banks are often at or below 3% ROI. It is important to not look at ROI as the *only* indicator of success, though. Many organizations are quite happy to earn a very small ROI as a trade off for being able to achieve other objectives (i.e. risk aversion or something else). So a strategy designed purely on a (possible) high ROI isn't always attractive, anyways.

Comment: This answer might be summarized as saying "banks aren't hedge funds/investment management companies".  However, most individuals also aren't investment management companies, yet as the OP mentions, there is a strong belief "that investing in the broad stock market ... is a very good investment strategy".  I feel like a more satisfying answer would include reasons that differentiate between banks and individual investors.  For example, as it stands, the discussion of not knowing "exactly how much cash you'll have next Tuesday" applies to my retirement account as well, as do coronavirus fears.

Comment: @A.Rex I guess I thought I'd covered that (at a high level at least) when I said things like, *Banks aren't just concerned about the expected outcome, they're also concerned about variability in the range of expected outcomes* and *But banks can't issue cash to deposit customers based on long term theories. They have to be able to predict the availability of funds very well.* I would consider expanding that paragraph more, but I'm trying to balance that against turning this answer into a giant wall of text. Maybe this can spur other, related questions if the OP feels the need for more detail.

Comment: @A.Rex "not knowing "exactly how much cash you'll have next Tuesday" applies to my retirement account as well" - Yes, someone with a stock market retirement account won't know exactly how much the account will be worth next Tuesday. The point is that, for a person with a retirement account, *that doesn't matter*. The only amount that matters there is the value of the account when the owner *actually retires*, which can be several decades away. The bank, on the other hand, needs to know that if Joe Billionaire withdraws $1 million next Tuesday, they'll be able to give it to him then and there.

Comment: @RonJohn, some people might be sentimentally attached to it being a car company and willing to give up profit for that even in a big companies upper management but I suspect that most of upper management would sell off the company if they really felt they had reliable data that they would beat the profit from their car company. I suspect that the real reason they do not is that they do not have that data. Just because they did worse than market for some year does not mean the same will happen for the next. More importantly just because your company is estimated to be worth  $46B ...

Comment: @RonJon,... it does not mean that they will be able to get that much money in liquid form by selling of assets. It might find that its value when converted to pure money is far less then $46B. If it ends up $20B and they get a few percent more return on that number than that is still less than the original 4.75% on the $46B number. You can probably predict the accurate "liquid" value of the company from its assets. And you will see that the value of the assets is far less than the value of the company based on the latest stock trades. Hence the percentage return might look higher, but be lower

Comment: (coronavirus did, in fact, take off in the US that weekend)

Answer (score 19):

### Because a "bank" like this will fail

The question assumes a "buy low, sell high" system, or even extreme "buy, never sell" investment scheme for the "bank".

But that you proposed is not a bank, it's a geared fund. Both have "clients". Clients that can withdraw at the worst possible moment.

Recessions come hand to hand with markets down runs. Long recessions will cause massive withdrawals, that will force the proposed bank/geared fund to sell its assets with spiraling smaller prices, until there is nothing left.

*Puff*, your bank just failed.

Comment: @NotThatGuy And now what you have is an investment fund, not a bank account :)

Comment: One of your contentions is that people withdraw money from the bank during long recessions or other bad moments.  But the same is true of people and their individual investment accounts.  Does the same reasoning suggest that people shouldn't invest money that they might want to withdraw?

Comment: @A.Rex That is actually true.  And generally why most people do not do well with private trading.

Comment: @NotThatGuy All banks I know of, not counting government run banks whose customers are normal banks, offer checking and saving accounts that allow penalty-free withdrawal of any amount at any time with no notice. These types of accounts are one of their major core products, to the point that I think they're a *defining feature* of banks. Calling something a bank *means* that it offers such accounts.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Essentially, the issue raised by your point is "why don't banks... not be banks?" Or, equivalently, "why do banks exist?" That's a fine question of its own, but it's beside the point for this discussion.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Your initial comment seemed to be suggesting that a bank could solve the problem you quoted by not having checking/saving accounts at all. Brondahl pointed out that such a bank would not be a bank, and I tried to clarify that point because you apparently didn't understand it.

Comment: Even if someone who withdraws cash long-term note within the next five years would have to pay a 10% penalty, a bank would still have to allow for the possibility that the person could demand to be paid 90% of the note's face value tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesn't any (serious) bank offer a savings account with a fixed 2%
>   interest rate for an unlimited amount of time?

I don't want to assume your age but you may not remember that this was actually a completely real situation in the past. When I was a growing up in the 80's I recall my basic savings account had an annual interest rate of somewhere between 3-5%. It is sad to me that in this "new normal" any rate above 1% for hard working savers is considered an amazing deal.

The reason ("why") this no longer occurs is somewhat due to the current economic climate of ultra low central bank interest/long term bond rates, money printing and vast explosion of debt and cheap credit.

Comment: In **2008** my _checking account_ had an interest rate of 6.25%. This 0-1% stuff is a major historical anomaly and is only due to the Fed holding rates artificially low for way too long.

Comment: I see your 6.25% and raise you 10%.  In **1981**, taxable Money Market accounts were paying nearly 17%.  Yes, inflation was high but 17% sure made you feel like a winner :-O

Answer (score 3):

Banks have to have enough assets to cover the value of savers’ deposits *at all times*. Just relying on having enough cash on hand to cover withdrawals is what Ponzi schemes and fraudsters do. (Note that the assets don’t have to be liquid, so banks can still run into trouble when they can’t call in the long-term loans they have made to cover a sudden rush of withdrawals.)

So if a bank takes $1 million in deposits and invests them in the stock market, which then has a bad year and falls by 5%, they now have $950,000 of assets backing $1,020,000 of deposits, and get shut down by the banking regulators (unless they can raise another $70,000 in capital from shareholders or asset sales or wherever).

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't any (serious) bank offer a savings account with a fixed 2% interest rate for an unlimited amount of time?

If they did that, I would do this:

- Divide my money 50-50 between the bank account and stocks
- Balance yearly.

That way I would end up taking money from the bank account whenever stocks are low, and put money there whenever stocks are high. If enough people did this, it would force the bank to do the opposite: buy when high and sell when low, so that they had money to return to the withdrawing customers. When only a small percentage of customers withdraws, the bank can also take more loan from central bank and keep holding the stocks.

The long term expected returns stops to apply as soon as some external event forces you to sell early. For example, if you need to sell stocks when you lose your job in a recession, you could end up with much worse returns than expected.

Comment: Except experience suggests that most people buy stocks when they’re doing well and sell them when they’re doing badly, the exact opposite of proper rebalancing, and so the banks would be forced to buy low and sell high rather than the other way around.

Comment: @MikeScott Yeah, one could of course gamble on the stupidity of people. But in that case, it is much easier to reap profits from crazy high transaction fees and issuing high-interest loans. And if there is a profit to be made, someone would exploit the smart way to use such fixed-interest bank accounts with billions of dollars of money.

Comment: Can you please expound why this "would force the bank to do the opposite: buy when high and sell when low"? Please don't hesitate to just edit your answer, rather than starting a comment chain.

Comment: "The long term expected returns stops to apply as soon as some external event forces you to sell early." That claim is contrary to the EMH.

Comment: @MikeScott that would suggest "most people" can't follow a simple 4-word instruction: buy low, sell high.

Comment: @Acccumulation Then it sounds like recessions themselves are contrary to your interpretation of EMH. On the other hand, one could just interpret it in the way that stock prices are a balance between interests of long-term investors and short-term investors, and when the interests of short-term investors drive the price down, long-term investors shouldn't sell.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Given that following that instruction requires violating the EMH, it's reasonable that many people are unable to do so.

Comment: @jpa Prices aren't a balance between interests, they reflect the interests of whoever has the best use for an asset. If a piece of land can grow $100,000 of wheat each year or $10,000 of pineapple, it's going to be priced according to the $100,000, not averaged out to $45,000.

Answer (score 0):

the boring answer to the question of why banks don't borrow cheap money from the fed and invest in the stock market is bc federal regulations don't allow banks to invest depositor money in the stock market.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really about how to handle risks.

The general rule in investments is a high rate of return = high risk. Stock markets carry a risk -- they can turn down very quickly but they generally have a higher rate of return than a savings account.

The regulations set on banks are there to protect the saving accounts from banks taking too much risk. You put money into your savings or checking account should be protected from the bank taking stupid risks and losing your money.

Each day the banks have to calculate the sum of the "risks" (see last paragraph below for the correct term) they have on the books according to special formulas. The bank is not allowed to take more risk than a limit, which in turn is calculated from the equity of the bank.

In effect, the equity of the bank company limits what kind and how much risk the bank can take. And the bank will try to maximize the profit given that.

Giving you a fixed interest saving account actually calculates as a risk -- the bank has promised to give you interest in the future. Owning stocks on the stock market calculates as a risk. Borrowing money from the central bank calculates as a risk.

So what you propose: fixed-rate interest against possible stock market gains and borrowing from the central bank sums to a risk, eating into the maximum risk the bank is allowed to take.

A smart bank manager maximizes the use of risk in order to gain maximum profit (and that is why the regulations are so complicated -- too many smart bank managers have done too many stupid things). The manager could use the bank's limited risk maximum towards giving saving accounts a fixed rate, or it could be used for other, more profitable things.

The point is that, right now, there is more risk-adjusted profit to have in other areas.

I use the word "risk" very loosely above. The actual term used is "Capital Adequacy Ratio" -- I suggest a google on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question displays that you're really interested in the subject matter, and that's great to see!  I'll answer your questions below, and I would helpfully suggest you do some background reading focusing on interest rates and credit risk.  If you really want to get crazy you can progress to mean variance portfolio theory, the capital asset pricing model and then understanding gambler's ruin and the kelly criterion.

The second question has been answered above-- because the regulators don't allow it.

As for the first question...

(#1) "Now comes the first question: Why doesn't any (serious) bank offer a savings account with a fixed 2% interest rate for an unlimited amount of time?"

You're contradicting yourself.  A savings account implies that the depositor can withdraw their money at any time while "an unlimited amount of time" implies that you're talking about a loan with a maturity far in the future.

Any bank would absolutely love to have someone lend money to them at 2% forever.  Heck, I'll take however many loans I can at 2% interest to be repaid never.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of what a money market account is. If you have a regular bank offering a regular savings account to members of the general public, that's commercial banking. If the money is invested in the stock market, that's investment banking. A commercial bank doing investment banking is very illegal. As in, you'd better have given millions of dollars to politicians or you're going to prison for a long time illegal.

> However, I feel that this is not really an objection because even without the above "obvious product" banks will always be in trouble if their customers want to withdraw too much money at once.

That's called a run on the bank. With a normal bank, even if there's a run, the deposits have been loaned out for things like mortgages, so the bank still has the mortgages to fall back on. They still have the assets, the assets just aren't very liquid. They can do things like sell the mortgages to other banks, or worst case scenario, there's the FDIC. If your money is in the stock market, and the stock money tanks, your assets aren't merely illiquid, they're flat-out worth less. And investing money protected by FDIC in the stock market? Again, super illegal.

Answer (score -1):

What other answers are forgetting about is **fractional reserve banking**.

In other words if bank invests the deposit at 3% they can not use that deposit to create money out of thin air(when they give loans).

Creating money out of thin air is more profitable than stock market investing.